# Python-Convert a list to dictionary with specific rule

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list

```
output = ['A', '', '', 'B', '', '', 'C', 'VariableC', 'vdn', 'L', 'D', '', '', 'E', '', '', 'F', '', '', 'G', '', '', 'H', '', '', 'I', '', '', 'J', '', '', 'K', '', '', 'L', '', '', 'M', '', '', 'N', '', '', 'O', '', '', 'P', '', '', 'Q', '', '', 'R', '', '']
```

I want to obtain a dictionary like below

```
new_dict = {'A': ['', ''],
            'B': ['',''],
            'C': ['VariableC','vdn','L'],
            'D': ['',''],
            ....,
            'R': ['','']}
```

I try to create a list as key_list for new_dict:

```
import string
alphabet_string = string.ascii_uppercase
alphabet_list = list(alphabet_string)[:-8]
```

Then, I tried to use a nested loop for `alphabet_list` and `output`, but I was at standstill when I saw 'L' and 'D' in `output` list

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: Why does the `'C'` key have 3 values in its list, while the rest of the keys only have 2?

Comment: can you explain your output? and provide code which making this output, so required output can be handled there not in the final form

Comment: @MattDMo: because It got value in the line 'C' with a table on the web that I got

Comment: @quamrana: It was just a nested loop but I saw the ill-logically when I saw the 'L' and 'D' item in the output list, then I've stopped.

Comment: @sahasrara62: the output came from a table in website element. A,B,C,D,...R are rows. If first column is empty, that row would contains 2 empty string like ' ' , ' '

Comment: @Scorpiscesi if this is web scrapping thing then  i suggest you to go through it again and you can scrap the data in required format preiously

Comment: @sahasrara62: I got the answer I need below. That works for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an approach that worked for me, albiet slightly messy code I hope that you can understand the logic behind it

```
import string
output = ['A', '', '', 'B', '', '', 'C', 'VariableC', 'vdn', 'L', 'D', '', '', 'E', '', '', 'F', '', '', 'G', '', '', 'H', '', '', 'I', '', '', 'J', '', '', 'K', '', '', 'L', '', '', 'M', '', '', 'N', '', '', 'O', '', '', 'P', '', '', 'Q', '', '', 'R', '', '']
letters = list(string.ascii_uppercase)
cur_letter = -1
data = {}
for item in output:
    if item == letters[cur_letter + 1]:
        data[letters[cur_letter + 1]] = []
        cur_letter += 1
    else:
        data[letters[cur_letter]].append(item)

print(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way of doing it. (maybe less efficient and but more robust).

```
output = ['A', '', '', 'B', '', '', 'C', 'VariableC', 'vdn', 'L', 'D', '', '', 'E', '', '', 'F', '', '', 'G', '', '', 'H', '', '', 'I', '', '', 'J', '', '', 'K', '', '', 'L', '', '', 'M', '', '', 'N', '', '', 'O', '', '', 'P', '', '', 'Q', '', '', 'R', '', '']

# Get the initial letter's ascii value
init_char = ord(output[0])

# Initialize the next char to be found 
next_char = init_char + 1 # Ascii of next char to be found
current_index = 1  # Index from which the values needs to be fetched

new_op_dict = {}

'''
Loop till the char is reached till Y(ASCII 89)
no need to loop if its Z so using 89 instead of 90

get the index of the next char
if present fetch the list between those two indices
break if the ValueError occurs
'''

while next_char<=89 :
    try :
        # search needs to be done only from the current_index+1 position
        till_index = output.index(chr(next_char), current_index+1)  
    except ValueError :
        till_index = len(output) # get the values till the end of list
        break
    finally:
        #next_char - 1 -> current char
        new_op_dict[chr(next_char - 1 )] = output[current_index: till_index]
        current_index = till_index + 1
        next_char = next_char + 1

print(new_op_dict)
```